# Epsilon Limit Proof (Bridge to Abstract Mathematics)

Tags: limits, divergent-series

For $(3n)$, how would I prove that the limit of $n$ approaching infinity does not exist?  Obviously this would diverge but I'm not completely sure how to prove it.  I know I have to use epsilon delta.

Comment: Not exactly.  In this case you'd have to use $\epsilon$ and $N$.  Specifically, suppose someone gives you a challenge $\epsilon >0$, and says, "Provide me with a positive integer $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$ you have $|3n-L|< \epsilon$." Prove there is no finite $L$ that works.

Comment: @Doc, that should probably be $|3n-L|<\epsilon$ for clarity.

Comment: @dfeuer, absolutely.  I think it must be bedtime.

Comment: @Doc, why don't you copy-paste the edited comment to make an answer, take some warm milk, and come back in the morning?

Comment: Hahahahahhaha .... good idea!

Comment: The limit of $3n$ is $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$. You said "it does not exist" which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! For the record, my teacher chose the words "does not exist." I think I figured it out, but please let me know if I'm missing something:
Assume lim(3n)=L as n approaches infinity and L is a real number. Let ϵ=1. Then for some natural number N, |3n−L|<1 for all n<N. Suppose n>(1/3) |L|+1.  Then 3n> |L|+1.  Thus,  |3n−L|>1=ϵ.  This creates a contradiction and therefore n diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $3n < \epsilon$. By the Archimedean property there exists an $n + \delta$ such that $3(n + \delta) > \epsilon$. Note that $\delta$ is a positive integer.